# Yammer Access Token Expiry

Tags: yammer

I am going through Yammer documentation.

I have found that currently access token do not expire as mentioned in the following link:
[https://developer.yammer.com/docs/authentication-1][1], point C.

Also, in the following link I could find that access token expires and we have to re-generate it via Oauth flow:
https://developer.yammer.com/docs/oauth-2, point C

I have couple of queries reagrding this:
1. What is the time duration for which the access token is valid
2. Is there any way to automate the token generation process.
3. Is there any limit on no. of Apps to be registered?

Let me know if you need any further details.

Thanks

Comment: I am facing same issue right now, Any suggestion @purva, Have you come out from this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer the question about which of those pages has it right, but it's possible you could use the Impersonation API endpoint to automate the (re)generation of access tokens for users.

Per https://developer.yammer.com/docs/impersonation:

> Impersonation allows you to request a valid access token on behalf of a user for your app. This action is restricted to verified Yammer admins, and only in paid Yammer networks.

Comment: In-order to work this, app should be created by verified yammer admin. Isn't it?